# Change selected value component in react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Is there any way to change the selected value component design, At my option menu, I show CscId and CscDesc but when I select the option, I only want to show CscId only. Is there any way to change the selected value component? I google for this one and it already took 1 day. Please Help me.

[image]

Here is my react-select

```
import React  from "react";
import Select from 'react-select';

const costcenterselect = ({ value, onChange, id, datasource }) => {    
  const formatOptionLabel = ({ CscID, CscDesc }) => (            
    <div style={{ display: "flex"}}>
      <div style={{width:'40%'}}>{CscID}</div>                
      <div>{CscDesc}</div>                
    </div>
  );  

  return (
    <div>
      <Select 
        id={id}
        menuIsOpen={true}    
        formatOptionLabel={formatOptionLabel}
        getOptionValue={option => `${option.CscID}`}
        options={datasource}
        onChange={onChange}
        defaultValue={value}        
      />
    </div>           
  )
}

export default costcenterselect;
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do it using `formatOptionLabel` itself. It has a second argument which provides you with meta information like `context` which you can use to conditionally render. Here is a [working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-value-vs-menu-option-p5wf8).

You can see that `context === value` allows you to render for selected value while `context === menu` renders for the options.

```
const formatOptionLabel = ({ CscID, CscDesc }, { context }) => {
    if (context === "value") {
      return <div>{CscID}</div>;
    } else if (context === "menu") {
      return (
        <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
          <div style={{ width: "40%" }}>{CscID}</div>
          <div>{CscDesc}</div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  };
```

Comment: OMG, Thank you so much, exactly what I want. May I know how you know this feature?

Comment: Glad it helped. Perhaps it's not easily accessible from `react-select`'s documentation, but on a closer look you can see that `formatOptionLabel` function's entire definition is [given there](https://react-select.com/props). Also, since it is open source, you can find a solution in [github issues](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/3485#issuecomment-476353482) too.